# jquery two event handlers one input field

Tags: jquery

I need to attach two Events to the same input field.  Please help.

I want to be able to attach an .blur()  along with the date picker on the same field.  Every time i try to have both events together they both break.

```
$.fn.valiDate = function () {

    $(this).datepicker({
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var myDate = $(this).val()

            if (myDate.length === 6) {
                day = myDate.substring(0, 2);
                month = myDate.substring(2, 4);
                year = myDate.substring(4);
                var myDateField = day + '/' + month + '/' + year
                try {
                    $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDateField, null);
                    $(this).val(myDateField)
                } catch (error) {
                    alert('Error 1:' + error);
                    $(this).val('')
                }

            } else if (myDate.length === 8 && myDate.indexOf('/') == -1) {
                day = myDate.substring(0, 2);
                month = myDate.substring(2, 4);
                year = myDate.substring(4);

                var myDateField = day + '/' + month + '/' + year

                try {
                    $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDateField, null);
                    $(this).val(myDateField)
                } catch (error) {
                    alert('Error 2:' + error);
                    $(this).val('')
                }

            } else if (myDate.length === 8 && myDate.indexOf('/') != -1) {
                try {
                    $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDate, null);
                    $(this).val(myDate)
                } catch (error) {
                    if (myDate != '--/--/--') {
                        alert('Error 3:' + error);
                        $(this).val('')
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert('Invalid Date');
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(.datefield).blur(function () {
                alert('hello');
            });
            $('#sbDinput').valiDate();

        });
```

Comment: A datepicker is hardly an event handler ?

Comment: And whatever errors you're seeing.  If you're using Firefox or Chrome hit F12.  That is the JS console and any errors will be printed there.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want the DatePicker to close when the field is exited?

Comment: I wrote a plugin to work with datepicker and it works great, i needed to do this because they want to enter dates manualy too as well as use the calendar. (i know right) but it only works with the close function in datepicker and leaves you in the field after an error and does not call the calendar again so it is not recalled on second entry.  I though i would change it, taking it out of the datepicker and attaching it to a blur() so when ever they left the field it would call it.  along with this i will now be able to just turnon the image so the calendar can be only activated by clicking

Comment: You know there's a built in option for that in jQuery datepicker, right! Image to click on and everything!

Comment: i searched a long time and did not find anything thing to do what i needed with the date, i am not clearing the field i want to re-validate the field again on new entry

Comment: i am not getting any error but my .blur() and my datepicker do not function.

Comment: The majority of the votes to close may have been made *before* you posted your code. (Bad form to ask question with no example code.) Therefore, edit your question a bit and re-post -- hopefully newly added code will fix. Also, are you sure the javascript itself isnt broken? Add an `alert('hi')` at the beginning of your `$.fn.valiDate=function(){}` function. I agree with adeneo: I suspect datepicker can already do all you need it to do.

Comment: I tried to format your code, but it looks like you have some missing closing braces and parens.

Comment: Aren't there missing semicolons at the ends of statements?

Comment: Even dumber, i missed my '' on my call above,     $(.datefield).blur(function ()

Comment: Either way i changed my approach and added the calendar.gif and took my code out and placed two functions in my plugin to handle the rest ill p9ost code

Answer (score 0):

the script is in the header and the plugin function section is in a series of stuff i have written for my shop because we use a hybrid code with out banking software.

```
  <script >
     $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('.dateField').valiDate();
       $('#sbDinput').datepicker({
         showOn: "button",
         buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
         buttonImageOnly: true
    });

      }); 
    </script>


    (function($) {


    $.fn.valiDate=function() {

     $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).val('');
      });
     $(this).change(function(){

        var myDate=$(this).val()

        if(myDate.length === 6) {

         day = myDate.substring(0, 2);
         month = myDate.substring(2, 4);
         year = myDate.substring(4);
        var myDateField=day+'/'+month+'/'+year
         try{
             $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDateField, null);
            $(this).val(myDateField)
            }
         catch(error){   
            alert('Error 1:'+error);
            $(this).val('')
                     }

       } else    if (myDate.length===8 && myDate.indexOf('/')==-1)
        {



         day = myDate.substring(0, 2);
         month = myDate.substring(2, 4);
         year = myDate.substring(4);

        var myDateField=day+'/'+month+'/'+year

         try{
             $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDateField, null);
            $(this).val(myDateField)
            }
         catch(error){   
            alert('Error 2:'+error);
            $(this).val('')
                     }

        }else    if (myDate.length===10 && myDate.indexOf('/')!=-1)
        {

         try{
             $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDate, null);
            $(this).val(myDate)
            }
         catch(error){  
             if (myDate!='--/--/--')
              {      
               alert('Error 3:'+error);
                $(this).val('')
              }
                     }
        }else if (myDate.length===8 && myDate.indexOf('/')!=-1)
        {

         try{
             $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', myDate, null);
            $(this).val(myDate)
            }
         catch(error){  
             if (myDate!='--/--/--')
              {      
               alert('Error 3:'+error);
                $(this).val('')
              }
                 }
                     }else {
               alert('Invalid Date');
               $(this).val(''); 
               }
    });        
    }







     })(jQuery);

    // end plugin
```